# How to generate multiple circle shapes and animate those shapes going down the frame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt

I am having trouble generating multiple oval shapes when clicking the panel of the frame. What I want is that it will generate many oval shapes and those shapes will move downward. One of the requirement is to use two multi threading. However in my case, the program I created is that, it will only generate one oval shape and the position is randomly changing. Can anyone please help me one this.

```
package ovalrandomcolors;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class OvalRandomColors extends JPanel{

    private int ovalX = 50;
    private int ovalY =50;
    private int ovalPositionX = 250;
    private int ovalPositionY = 250;
    private Color color = Color.YELLOW;

    public OvalRandomColors(){
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);


        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(ovalPositionX, ovalPositionY, ovalX, ovalY);

        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(ovalPositionX, ovalPositionY, ovalX, ovalY);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
               JFrame frame = new JFrame();
               final OvalRandomColors oval = new OvalRandomColors();
               oval.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                   @Override
                   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                       OvalWithThreading firstThread = new OvalWithThreading(oval);
                       OvalWithThreading secondThread = new OvalWithThreading(oval);

                       Thread first = new Thread(firstThread);
                       Thread second = new Thread(secondThread);
                       second.start();
                       first.start();
                   }
               });

               frame.add(oval);
               frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
               frame.setSize(500,700);
               frame.setVisible(true);
            }  
        });      
    }


    public void updateOval(){

        int r = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        int g = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int b = (int)(Math.random() * 255);

        color = new Color(r,g,b);

        ovalPositionX = (int)(Math.random() * 78);
        ovalPositionY = (int) (Math.random() * 245);

        animateOval();
        repaint();
    }
    public void animateOval(){
           // ovalPositionX += 30;
            ovalPositionY += 30;
    }

    public static class OvalWithThreading implements Runnable{

        private final OvalRandomColors ovalShape;
        public OvalWithThreading(OvalRandomColors oS){
            this.ovalShape = oS;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(;;){
                    ovalShape.updateOval();
                try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OvalRandomColors.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }           
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need a `List` of some kind, into which you can add new rectangles and from which you can move and draw.  Generally speaking a Swing `Timer` would be a better solution than using `Thread` as Swing is not thread safe

Comment: @MadProgrammer as what i've read also. However one of the requirement is to use thread for now. Can you please give example on how to implement list?

Comment: [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with, Swing is not `Thread` safe, so having another `Thread` which update the state of objects which the UI depends to render requires some serious considerations.  Normally, I'd recommend using a Swing `Timer` or `SwingWorker` to accomplish this, but those aren't the "requirements"

In order to render multiple objects, you need some way to store them, so you can update their states and renderer them.  The simplest solution is a `List`, you can see [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details.

[image: DropBalls]

Now, if you also need to manage color, you can take a look at how I managed the deltas for each shape and should give you one idea for doing that

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private ReentrantLock shapesLock = new ReentrantLock();
        private List<Ellipse2D> shapes;

        public TestPane() {
            shapes = new ArrayList<>(25);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    shapesLock.lock();
                    try {
                        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(e.getX() - 5, e.getY() - 5, 10, 10));
                    } finally {
                        shapesLock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                private Map<Shape, Double> deltas = new HashMap<>();

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            shapesLock.lock();
                            try {
                                Rectangle containerBounds = getBounds();
                                containerBounds.setLocation(0, 0);
                                Iterator<Ellipse2D> it = shapes.iterator();
                                while (it.hasNext()) {
                                    Ellipse2D shape = it.next();
                                    Rectangle2D bounds = shape.getBounds2D();
                                    double y = bounds.getY();
                                    Double delta = deltas.get(shape);
                                    if (delta == null) {
                                        delta = 0d;
                                    }
                                    y += delta;
                                    shape.setFrame(bounds.getX(), y, bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
                                    if (containerBounds.contains(shape.getBounds())) {
                                        delta = Math.min(delta + 0.25, 6d);
                                        deltas.put(shape, delta);
                                    } else {
                                        it.remove();
                                    }
                                }
                            } finally {
                                shapesLock.unlock();
                            }
                            repaint();
                            Thread.sleep(40);
                        }   catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            t.setDaemon(false);
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            shapesLock.lock();
            try {
                for (Ellipse2D shape : shapes) {
                    g2d.fill(shape);
                }
            } finally {
                shapesLock.unlock();
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you again. You're so great i am learning new things that helps me  improve my skills in java

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry to bother you but one of the requirements I overlooked was to use two threads. The sample program was using list to create another oval shape. Do I just need to instantiate new Thread and use the start() method?

Comment: @JayGorio You want a second thread which generates the dots instead of the mouse click?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No the creation of shapes will still be there upon clicking the mouse what I want is that I will create two threads when animating the oval shape. There were changes in the requirement by the way. The first ball will animate by bouncing across the border of the frame using infinite loop. So when the ball hit the outside bottom border of the frame it will continue move up and so on. also when hitting the top most of the frame it will go down. Next when clicking again the panel, there will be a second ball that will animate that will follow the first ball  and there will be delay.

Comment: @MadProgrammer What iI am confused about is that, is it necessary to create two threads to create this?But in fact one thread can handle those requirements in swing. right?

Comment: @JayGorio One thread is not only suitable, it would be recommended, adding more threads doesn't always mean things run faster, in fact, it can make somethings run slower