# Cannot see oval shape moving down the panel

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, awt

I have this program that when a user click on panel, the oval shape will move downward the panel. I printed the yLocation (location of the oval on y coordinate) using System.out.print and I can see the values changing. But the problem is that I cannot view the oval shape moving.

```
public class OvalWithThreading {

public OvalWithThreading(){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Click On The Canvas");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new OvalPane());
            frame.pack() ;
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new OvalWithThreading();
}

//Panel that will hold the oval shape
public class OvalPane extends JPanel{

    private int xPosition = 50;
    private int yPosition = 50;
    private int xSize = 50;
    private int ySize = 50;
    boolean clicked = true;
    boolean horizontalBoundary = true;
    boolean verticalBoundary = true;

    private List<Ellipse2D> shapes;

    public OvalPane(){
        shapes = new ArrayList<>();
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                if(clicked) clicked = false;
                else if(!clicked) yPosition = 50; 

                shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPosition, yPosition , 50, 50)); 
                System.out.print("Clicked");
                repaint();
            }

       });
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        for (Ellipse2D shape : shapes) {
            g2d.fill(shape);
            Rectangle2D bounds = shape.getBounds2D();
            double yPos = bounds.getY();
            double xPos = bounds.getX();
            shape.setFrame(xPos, yPos, bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `yPosition` has no relationship to the shape once the shape is made (it has to do with the way that Java passes parameters and is a good thing), so no matter how much you change it, it will have no effect on your shapes.

You also have multiple shapes, so you don't want them all to have the same value anyway.

As was outlined in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837747/how-to-generate-multiple-circle-shapes-and-animate-those-shapes-going-down-the-f), you need to iterate over each shape and update it's position, for example...

```
for (Ellipse2D shape : shapes) {
    Rectangle2D bounds = shape.getBounds2D();
    double yPos = bounds.getY();
    yPos += 30;
    shape.setFrame(bounds.getX(), yPos, bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: When the oval is moving downward I can see no the oval but when its going up I cannot see the oval moving. What I did was to assign the ypos = yPosition and its working. But the first oval created upon clicking the panel will be gone and the second will animate. What I want is that I can see them both animating downward and upward. How can i achieve this?

Comment: I had multiple ovals sliding down. If you assign yPosition to ypos then it will do nothing as the values won't change

Comment: Thank you. But how can I achieve that?

Comment: @JayGorio Achieve what? Have multiple balls slide down the screen?  Update you code to use my code, that's all I did

Comment: Yeah I did that that was the first requirement. However they change it. The ball should continue animating across the panel. If the ball goes down and exceeded the horizontal or vertical boundary the ball should move up or move to the left.

Comment: what I did was I make use of flag. See my answer

Comment: Be very careful with modifying the original answer, it's lost all of it's context in relationship to the answer provided. If you need to do more beyond the original question you really should create a new question, if it's relevant, linking them to previous questions

Comment: Yeah I mistakenly deleted I think. I will modify it again.

Answer (score 1):

You block Event Dispather Thread by your sleep(). Use [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead. In the actionPerformed() change `y` and call repaint()

UPDATE:

Place the repaint() in SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() to let EDT perform repaint

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot use Timer since that is not the requirement. I need to use Thread.

Comment: @StanislavL Stas invokeAndWait() required to be out of EDT

Comment: `repaint` by it's nature is thread safe, the repaint will post a "repaint event" onto the event queue independently

Comment: Also, what is the relationship between `yPosition` and the multiple instances of `Ellipse2D` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;;){   
if(horizontalBoundary){
    if((yPosition += 30) >= getHeight()-50){
        horizontalBoundary = false;
    }

}else if(!horizontalBoundary){
    if((yPosition -= 30)<= 0){
        horizontalBoundary = true;
    }
}
if(verticalBoundary){
    if((xPosition += 30) >= getWidth()-50){
        verticalBoundary = false;
    }
}else if(!verticalBoundary){
    if((xPosition -= 30) <= 0){
        verticalBoundary = true;
    }
}
System.out.println(yPosition + " " + xPosition);
  repaint();
```